# where is products images column in magento2 database?

Tags: magento2, product-images

where is products images column in magento2 database? i want to make a querey to check those products who haven't images wont come and products with only images comes on my homepage product list .

please elaborate if anybody knows : i figured out this table

```
(select * from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery)
```

there are some images inside this table , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have flat table enabled then you can also search for `image` column in `catalog_product_flat` table.

Magento uploads images by creating multiple directories based on image name

**For example:**

My image name is `11000_3008x1990_a.jpg`, magento will create 2 directory with starting initial name 1 and other directory with name 1 hence my image path would be

> pub/media/catalog/product/1/1/11000_3008x1990_a.jpg

Similarly Check your images under this path

> pub/media/catalog/product/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this table doesn't exist brother , i am using codazon/product_filter extension

Comment: That why I have mentioned that if flat table is enabled, to enable it you can go to Admin panel -> System-> Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Frontend->Use Flat Catalog Product->Yes. You should enable it only it is suitable for your website.

Comment: alright i enabled it but still that table is not present in my db

Comment: For this you will need to run the indexing command